# Why was my "possible duplicate" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

I raised a "possible duplicate" flag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963505/c-calling-method-of-subclass-in-superclass) as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355195/check-for-derived-type-c) because the first two answers of the latter question provide examples of how to do what the former was asking. In fact, the only answer for the former question is basically the same suggestion as the first (accepted) answer to the latter question. It is my impression that even if the questions are not exactly the same, they should be marked duplicate if they're close enough such that the answers will be the same. Is that not correct? If it is correct, why was my flag declined?

Comment: It was declined in review when three reviewers voted to leave it open: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13347078

Comment: Hm. But was my flag incorrect, or did I just happen to get three incorrect reviews in a row?

Comment: My C++ is rusty enough that I can't make a good judgment on the duplicate. I will note that only one of the three reviewers seems to have any experience in this area, which is usually needed for judging duplicates.

Comment: We need more information.  If the class is not polymorphic then `dynamic_cast` will not work

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean like Tavian noted in the comments, right?